# Export the elevation values and its corresponding lat and long as a csv file in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, csv, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to export the ground elevation (elev_lowestmode) values from the GEDI L2A monthly raster data set (ee.ImageCollection("LARSE/GEDI/GEDI02_A_002_MONTHLY").

I need the elevation values and the corresponding lat and long as a CSV file. I've tried many ways to export them. I am getting the elevation values but not the lat and long. The due date of my project is expiring.

This is one of the codes I tried but didn't work. I'm getting only 25 elevation values and the code for getting lat an long showed many errors. so i haven't added that in this code
https://code.earthengine.google.com/c000e3f6901b63d3a3affc67dc279bc8

```
  return im.updateMask(im.select('quality_flag').eq(1))
      .updateMask(im.select('degrade_flag').eq(0));
};
var gedi = ee.ImageCollection('LARSE/GEDI/GEDI02_A_002_MONTHLY')
                  .map(qualityMask)
                  .select('elev_lowestmode');

var gediVis = {
  min: 1,
  max: 60,
  palette: 'darkred,red,orange,green,darkgreen',
};
// Map.setCenter(-74.803466, -9.342209, 10);
Map.addLayer(gedi, gediVis, 'elev_lowestmode');

// Define a function to clip imagecollection.
var ImageCollection = ee.ImageCollection('LARSE/GEDI/GEDI02_A_002_MONTHLY')
var clip_fn = function(image) {
var ClippedImage = image.clip(geometry);
  return ClippedImage;
};
// Map the function over the collection.
var ImageCol_clip = ImageCollection.map(clip_fn);

// Clip the GEDI L2 dataset to the region of interest
var clippedGedi = gedi.map(function(img) {
  return img.clip(geometry);
});

// Create the digital elevation model by taking the mean of all the images
var dem = clippedGedi.mean().int();

// Create a feature collection of pixels in the dem
var pixels = dem.reduceToVectors({
  geometry: geometry,
  scale: 1000,
  geometryType: 'polygon',
  eightConnected: false,
  labelProperty: 'elevation',
});

Map.addLayer(ImageCol_clip);
// Clip the GEDI L2 dataset to the region of interest
var clippedGedi = gedi.map(function(img) {
  return img.clip(geometry);
});

// Export the feature collection as a CSV file
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: pixels,
  description: 'ALP elevation',
  selectors: ('elevation'),
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

I know this code needs a lot of modification but this is the best i could come up with as of now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be change this in your code:

```
var pixels = dem.reduceToVectors({
  geometry: geometry,
  scale: 1000,//1000m is the reason why you have only 25,to get ~each pixel value, you must change it to 25m(GEDI resolution)   
  geometryType: 'centroids',//I would suggest the centroid of the pixels 
  eightConnected: false,
  labelProperty: 'elevation',
});

// Export the feature collection as a CSV file
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: pixels,
  description: 'ALP elevation',
  selectors: ['elevation','.geo'],//add ".geo" to get the coordinates or simply deleted the selectors to get all properties
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

If you want the lat/long as an independent attribute, just add this before to export:

```
//get lat long
var proj = dem.select([0]).projection()
var latlon = ee.Image.pixelLonLat()
dem = dem.addBands(latlon.select('longitude','latitude'))

//extract lat lon
pixels=dem.select('longitude').reduceRegions(pixels, ee.Reducer.mean().setOutputs(['long']), 25)
pixels=dem.select('latitude').reduceRegions(pixels, ee.Reducer.mean().setOutputs(['lat']), 25);
```

To know more about **ee.Image.reduceToVectors** check [this](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-reducetovectors)

Here an example [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/00d1806ce8c9c73edbf55254332ea23a)

Comment: @david, This code seems to be working. but all the values that I'm getting are negetive. and they too in -90,-80,-60 ranges. So I want to know if I want to get the ground elevation is there a better value to use rather than the elev_lowestmode in gedi data. I thought of using rh1 or rh25. Will that work fine?

Comment: @David, can i get the lat and long as seperate tables instead of it in .geo?

Comment: @nawraparveen I’m not sure of the answer about you first comment. But for the second comment, sure!! I updated my answer explaining how to extract lat/lon as independent attribute; also, the link of the example was updated.  If you find it useful, consider mark the answer as accepted for future references.

Comment: @david sure thankyou